# Buscador, select, options, php

Tags: php, select, buscador, options

Buen dia, estoy construyendo un buscador que incluye cuadro de texto y categorias.
Por ejemplo:

```
<div>
<form method="GEt" action="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group primw">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="busq" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['busq'])){echo"$busq";}else{echo"";}?>"
                    placeholder="Escribe..."/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <select id="categoria" name="cat" class="form-control" aria>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-2 bbuscar">
                <button type="submit" name="buscar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Mi problema y pregunta es que después de hacer una búsqueda por `Get`, quiero que se muestre la `option` que coincide con la categoria de busqueda que hice .
Por ejemplo si mi busqueda fue  **Arroz** y la categoria fue  **3**. Cuando me muestre los resultados, en el input saldrá  **Arroz** y quiero que en el select en lugar que salga **1** por defecto, aparezca el **3**.
¿Como lo hago?

Comment: Considera leer [ask], editar y tratar de proveer un [mcve] donde veamos que has intentado y que problemas puntuales has tenido

Comment: Podrías proporcionar mas información, de favor. Algo que pueda ayudar a replicar el ejemplo. De favor.

Comment: Y tu Query SQL, la estructura de tu bd, la manera en que hacen el backend de tu aplicacion? Ahi solo muestras una plantilla HTML y nomas

Answer (score 0):

Si aun no has podido solucionar te echo la mano, esto es un ejemplo el cual puedes modificar para que puedas modificar y trabajar con el, ya que no has entregado mucha información, salvo el archivo en HTML.

La tabla de la base de datos que use era sencilla, solo tenia 2 campos: `id, name` y esta tabla se llama `foods`;

Para este ejemplo se ha usado bootstrap, lo que se debe hacer para ello es lo siguiente:

1. Crear una conexión hacia la Base de Datos
2. Crear tu formulario donde buscaras el dato que necesitas
3. Verificar que exista el campo que vamos a buscar y crear la query
4. Ejercicio completo.

- Paso 1: Crear una conexión hacia la Base de Datos.

Para ello, abrimos tu archivo `index.php` y agregamos este pedazo de código.

```
<?php 
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tu_usuario", "tu_passwd");
  if(!$connection){
    echo "He fallado al conectarme a la base de datos";
    exit();
  }
  mysqli_select_db($connection, 'tu_bd_name') or die("No BD");
  mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
?>
```

- Paso 2: Crear tu formulario donde buscaras el dato que necesitas.
  Un simple formulario con un campo y el submit para no variar

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" class="form-control">
  <label for="search" class="form-label">
    <span class="form-label">Buscar por nombre</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre manualmente">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar!">
</form>
```

- Paso 4: Verificar que exista el campo que vamos a buscar y crear la query
  Esta es un poco más sencilla, solo agregamos un if para validar  y que no se muestre el mensaje `Undefine index: $_GET['un_dato_random'];`

```
<option selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search = $_GET['search']; 
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM foods WHERE name LIKE '$search'";
    $statement = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
          
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
      echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
  }
?>
```

- Paso 4: Ejercicio completo:
  Si no te funciona los snippets, no hay problema, te adjunto el código completo

```
  <main style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h1 class="text-align-center">Buscador</h1>
    <section class="container mt-5" id="search-container">
      <?php 
      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
      if(!$connection){
        echo "He fallado al conectarme a la base de datos";
        exit();
      }
      mysqli_select_db($connection, 'pildoras_informaticas') or die("No BD");
      mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
      ?>
      <h2>Si no lo encuentras, buscalo por su nombre</h2>

      <form action="index.php" method="get" class="form-control">
        <label for="search" class="form-label">
          <span class="form-label">Buscar por nombre</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre manualmente">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar!">
      </form>
    </section>
    <hr>

    <section class="container mt-4" id="selector-container">
      <legend>Mostrando el que ha buscado</legend>
      <select class="form-select" name="food_selection" id="food_selection">
        <option selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
        <?php
          if(isset($_GET['search'])){
            $search = $_GET['search'];
            
            $query = "SELECT id, name FROM foods WHERE name LIKE '$search'";
            
            $statement = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
          
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
              echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
            }
          }
        ?>
      </select>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Espero que te ayude a solucionar lo que buscas :)